# Oracle List of all Tables, values in table

Tags: oracle, tableau-api, database-administration

I am trying to develop report in tableau with back end as oracle.

I have a database where I have 30 owners and 20 tables in each owner , so is there a way in oracle I can display all data in tables per owner.

My Query :

```
Select distinct Owner as t1,Table_Name as t2  From All_Tables Where Owner='I7I  And Table_Name Like '%UPDATE'
```

I am only getting Owner name and table name, unable to get data related to that particular table.
Some one please guide me.

Thanks
Addy

Comment: Do you want all tables from all the owners ?

Comment: yes I need from all owners..

Comment: Are you hand writing SQL or connecting to the Owner table and letting Tableau generate the SQL based on the fields you use in Tableau? It is usually best to let Tableau generate the SQL unless you are using some rare database specific function.

Comment: I am hand writing sql since I need all Owner and table names and all data in those tables, if Sugest me if you have any good idea

Comment: Can you just connect Tableau to the All_Tables table or view? That would be simpler if the driver gives you access to that table

Comment: @AlexBlakemore :All tables and All table_columns will give me names but i need count in my data.

Comment: @addy, do you run Oracle table statistics on your tables and if so, would the num_rows from the statistics be accurate enough for your purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a view on the above of all tables and try using that view in Tablea

Answer (score 0):

You can join `all_tables` (or `user_tables`) to the statistics table. Something like this (in the `sys` or schema if dragging tables in Tableau).

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_tab_statistics ust
       JOIN user_tables ut ON (ust.table_name = ut.table_name)
```

You can also change that to the all_* tables instead and join using `schema_name` in addition to `table_name`.

`user_tab_statistics` will have a column for the number of rows. Of course, this assumes you are gathering table statistics and you don't mind the row count being up-to-the-minute current.